# Generating random number from range on click, that isn't the same as previous numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables, random

I don't really know what I'm doing but been playing with jQuery trying to achieve this. I had the functionality working fine with the exception of occasionally showing the same testimonial twice in a row, which I'm trying to solve. Here is my attempted code which doesn't compute, I'm quite sure it's something obvious that I don't understand! Any help is appreciated.

You can see the intended functionality here in the testimonial footer: https://blue-coast-f4d2bc.webflow.io/contact

```
     function getNumber(previous) {
  if (previous === undefined) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1;
      return i;
  }
  else {
    while {
      i = previous; 
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1;
    }
    return i;
  }


var quoteNumb = getNumber();
 $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').addClass('show');
  
  var footHeight = $('.testimonial-container').height();
$('.testimonial-container').css({'min-height': footHeight  + 'px'});
  $('.testimonial-container').css({'max-height': footHeight  + 'px'});
  
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".refresh-button").click(function() {
                $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').removeClass('show');
                  quoteNumb = getNumber(quoteNumb);
                $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').addClass('show');
                $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: This `while { i = previous; i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1; }` does not make sense. I guess you intended to compare `i == previous` and to put that as the condition of the `while` loop. Also, `getNumber()` is only called once in your code, and with no `previous` parameter.

Comment: The intention is to generate a new number on the refresh-button click, which is not the same number as the immediately previous one.

So as long as i==previous this condition has not been met and I have to generate a new number again from the list of 14. Can't figure out how to achieve it though as I keep breaking the code.

Comment: `do { i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1; } while (i === previous);`

Comment: Brilliant that seems to have worked! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a random sequence that will determine which order the testimonials appear in. This way they will not repeat until all items have appeared.

We start by creating a sequence like 0,1,2,3,4 ... N, then we shuffle it using (in this case) a [`Fisher-Yates`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) type shuffle.

Once we have our sequence created, getting the next item is easy. In this example, we cycle through all items, then return to the start.

```js
let state = 0;

let sequence = getRandomSequence(1, 6);

function getRandomSequence(start, length) {
    return shuffle(generateRange(start, length))
}
  
function generateRange(start, length) {
    return Array.from({ length }, (v,k) => k + start)
}
  
// Fisher-Yates shuffle
function shuffle(arr) {
    arr = [...arr];
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    }
    return arr;
}

// Should drop in as a replacement...
function getNumber() {
    return sequence[(state++) % sequence.length];
}

quoteNumb = getNumber();

function showNextQuote() {
    $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').removeClass('show');
        quoteNumb = getNumber(quoteNumb);
        $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').addClass('show');
        $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').fadeIn(1000);
    });
}

showNextQuote();
```

```css
.footer-testimonial-quote
{ 
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show 
{ 
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button onclick='showNextQuote()'>
Next quote
</button>
<br><br>

  <div class="footer-testimonial-quote">What a great product!</div>
  <div class="footer-testimonial-quote">Great product!</div>
  <div class="footer-testimonial-quote">Love it</div>
  <div class="footer-testimonial-quote">Amazing</div>
  <div class="footer-testimonial-quote">Meh</div>
  <div class="footer-testimonial-quote">Awesome, would recommend</div>
```

Comment: I really like this idea however for my application the Testimonials are stored as CMS items, displayed in a list of all of them, and then shown based on adding a .show class using the javascript. I tried to adapt your code to this purpose as below but doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: I'll actually update to use a getNumber() function just like in your original example. This should be easy to adapt to your code!

Comment: I've updated to show the nth element in the list..

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot Terry I appreciate you taking the time to do that! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   let quotes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

let state = 0;

let sequence = getRandomSequence(0, quotes.length);

function getRandomSequence(start, length) {
    return shuffle(generateRange(start, length))
}
  
function generateRange(start, length) {
    return Array.from({ length }, (v,k) => k + start)
}
  
// Fisher-Yates shuffle
function shuffle(arr) {
    arr = [...arr];
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    }
    return arr;
}

function nextInSequence() {
    let quoteNumb = quotes[sequence[(state++) % sequence.length]];
    $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').addClass('show');
          $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').fadeIn(1000);
}

nextInSequence();

$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".refresh-button").click(function() {
        $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $('.footer-testimonial-quote:nth-of-type('+quoteNumb+')').removeClass('show');
                  nextInSequence();
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Nice answer Adam :-)